# Showing task progress from a Django management command

Tags: python, django, django-logging

I have some Django management commands that call methods in other classes to fetch data from APIs. These tasks can take a long time to complete, and I'd like to show progress in the console in a concise manner.

I could use `print()` to output a single line like "Fetched 22 of 3000" that writes over itself, using something like:

```
print('Fetched %d of %d' % (n, total) + ' '*30, end='\r')
```

But using `print()` seems a bit nasty, and it gets output to the console when tests are run. So it seems better to use [logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/logging/), but I can't see a way using that to display a single, constantly updated, "progress" line in the console.

Is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: If you use `self.stdout.write` and `self.stderr.write` instead of `print`, you can pass `os.devnull` to `call_command` for stdout/stderr kwargs in your tests and it won't output to the console.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe [tqdm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm) is a helpful python package for you.

Comment: I hadn't seen that before, and you may be right. One thing though - I'm not sure how to disable its console output while running unit tests. Any ideas?

Comment: @PhilGyford you can set the `disable=True` argument.